# How to separate main activity and date picker to own classes

Tags: android, class, android-widget, singleton, datepicker

This little thing started to frustrate me a lot. I thought it was something simle to do, but I think I haven't understood clearly how android works.

Anyway, the problem is that my android application will have some buttons that will open a date or time picker dialog box when pressed. I know how to implement them directly in the same class as the main activity itself, but I don't think that's good solution for maintenance reasons and also if I'm going to develop that application further some day.

I tried to do this by several different ways and failed every time I tried to do it. That left me pretty clueless of what to do and what's the problem.

Here's one way I tried to do this:

the main activity (I simplified it and tried to provide only the necessary code, because it's long). This is following the singleton design pattern.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    dateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editDateButton);

    dateButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view.getId() == R.id.editStartDateButton) {
        DatePickers.getInstance().setDate(dateButton);
    }
}
```

The date pickers class (extends Activity; also simplified code and all the unnecessary things removed):

```
private static DatePickers self = null;

public static DatePickers getInstance() {
    if (null == self) {
        self = new DatePickers();
    }
    return self;
}

public void setDate(Button button) {
    theButtonUsed = button;
    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
}
```

After the showDialog call the class is similar to the example [Hello-DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html) in android developer site.

Also I tried to do it pretty much like in [here](http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-3-more-views), but with the differnece that when the dateButton is clicked it starts the new activity that's the date picker dialog. In this case the datePicker class was like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.datePicker);

    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
}
```

And the rest as it is in the Hello-DatePicker example in android dev site. Both these solutions lead to a problem where my application crashed and was forced to quit.

I hope you understand what's the problem and that you could guide me and show what I'm doing wrong. I tried to make this short and provide only the necessary information.

Thanks
-Z

Edit:

As I have mentioned in one of the comments, the real problem with this was that I has simply forgotten to add the new activity to the manifest file. There might have been some other problems that was solved with the accepted answer. I hope this is still helpful to anyone facing similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can help you out there.

I know my solution isn't going to follow your singleton approach but it definitely separates DatePicker code from the calling Activity or Activities - which in return becomes modular and clean.

So here it goes:
Below is the designated DatePicker code (I named it DateSelector).  You start this activityForResult and it will return a bundle with Day, Month, and Year to the calling Activity.

I'm also going to pasting the simple layout DateSelector uses right below it; it's just a transparent layout...

```
package com.cyberfabric.historicise.activities;

import java.util.Calendar;

import com.cyberfabric.historicise.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Window;


public class DateSelector extends Activity{

    private final static int DIALOG_DATE_PICKER = 0;

    private int setYear;
    private int setMonth;
    private int setDay;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.date_picker);

        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        setYear = today.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        setMonth = today.get(Calendar.MONDAY);
        setDay = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        showDialog(DIALOG_DATE_PICKER); 
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
        switch(id){
            case DIALOG_DATE_PICKER:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, setYear, setMonth, setDay);
            }
        return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            setYear = year;
            setMonth = month;
            setDay = day;
            returnDate();
        }
    };


    /*
     * Package up the data and return it back to the calling intent
     */
    private void returnDate(){
        Intent intent = getIntent();    // calling/parent intent //

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("year", setYear);
        bundle.putInt("month", setMonth);
        bundle.putInt("day", setDay);
        intent.putExtra("set_date", bundle);

        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);

        finish();
    }
}
```

Here is the layout DateSelector uses:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    />
```

Your calling Activity or Activities should launch DateSelector as such:

```
// some global variable declared in order to start activityForResult and to catch 
// it back on onActivityResult
private final static int REQUEST_GET_DATE = 3;
```

Starting the DateSelector from the calling Activity:

```
Intent dp = new Intent(EventForm.this, DateSelector.class);
EventForm.this.startActivityForResult(dp, REQUEST_GET_DATE);
```

And finally in your calling Activity just catch it onActivityResult:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){ 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 

    switch(requestCode){ 
        case REQUEST_GET_DATE:
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                Bundle setDate = data.getBundleExtra("set_date");
                int setDay = setDate.getInt("day");
                int setMonth = setDate.getInt("month");
                int setYear = setDate.getInt("year");
                System.out.println(setDay + " " + setMonth + " " + setYear);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps, hope you like it,

Best,

-serkan

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This worked after some modification, though the real reason for this problem was really noobish: I had forgotten to add the new activity to the manifest file :3

Comment: which modifications u apply? it didn't work in original form? would be useful for others if u comment or edit original answer by serkan.. 10q